# postgresql table columns

Tags: c, postgresql

I am dealing with postgresql table columns. It's easy in SQL or pl/pgSQL, but how to handle columns(e.g. get column name, get the number of columns of a table, check whether a column with name XXX exists in a table) in PL/C?

Answer (score 1):

You mean things like:

```
PQnfields
Returns the number of columns (fields) in each row of the query result.

int PQnfields(const PGresult *res);
PQfname
Returns the column name associated with the given column number. Column numbers start at 0. The caller should not free the result directly. It will be freed when the associated PGresult handle is passed to PQclear.

char *PQfname(const PGresult *res,
              int column_number);
NULL is returned if the column number is out of range.

PQfnumber
Returns the column number associated with the given column name.

int PQfnumber(const PGresult *res,
              const char *column_name);
-1 is returned if the given name does not match any column.

The given name is treated like an identifier in an SQL command, that is, it is downcased unless double-quoted. For example, given a query result generated from the SQL command

select 1 as FOO, 2 as "BAR";
we would have the results:

PQfname(res, 0)              foo
PQfname(res, 1)              BAR
PQfnumber(res, "FOO")        0
PQfnumber(res, "foo")        0
PQfnumber(res, "BAR")        -1
PQfnumber(res, "\"BAR\"")    1
```

Taken from [Postgres Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-SELECT-INFO).

What problems are you having?  The calls are pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Changed link to current manual. Why would you link to the outdated version 8.2?

Comment: I'm sorry if I did't ask the questions clearly. What I want to know is how to do this internally, since I was programming 'inside' postgres instead of interacting with postgres using libpq.Struct TableInfo seems could solve my problem:http://doxygen.postgresql.org/pg__dump_8h_source.html @wadesworld